# Write the sum of the values in to another file using Nodejs asynchronously

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, fs

I have a file readData.txt has the values `"10,20,30,40,50,........"`like this I have the numbers.

Now I want to write the sum of those values in to the other file called sumfile.txt. I'm using `fs.readFile and fs.writeFile` functions which are asynchronous.

I have tried using Promises, It worked. But I'm curious that can we do it without using Promises. I'm trying to achieve that without Promises.

If anybody know any other ways I'll be thankful.

Comment: Using promises is... Promising. It helps you avoid the callback hell.

Comment: Thank you @Lajos Arpad, The thing is I just want to dig the NodeJs deeper. The main requirement is I have numbers in that file which I'm reading, I want to add those values and I want to store that sum in to another file, Being Asynchronous read and write I'm not sure how much data I'll get at each iteration, So is there any other ways to do this other than Promises?

Comment: I have given you examples using callbacks, which are not promises. However, they are asynchronous too. You need to implement the logic you need after the async operation into the fulfillment of the promise or into the callback. This is the way to go, doing this synchronously is anti pattern and should be avoided.

Comment: Yeah I got an idea ,Thanks a lot, Your help much appreciated:)

Comment: You are welcome. In the meantime I edited my answer to give you information about how you can do this synchronously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the callback parameter of `fs.readFile`:

```
fs.readFile('/etc/passwd', (err, data) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(data);
});
```

You can use the callback parameter of `fs.writeFile`:

```
const data = new Uint8Array(Buffer.from('Hello Node.js'));
fs.writeFile('message.txt', data, (err) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('The file has been saved!');
});
```

EDIT

You can do this synchronously as well, using `fs.readFileSync`

```
fs.readFileSync('<directory>');
```

and `fs.writeFileSync`

But it is better to keep things async. It is difficult at first, but all your struggles will be rewarded.